# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hey there i've been trying to display a image to the background of my page but its not working i keep getting the error

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
"http://killerducky1.x10.mx/images/offline.png". killerducky1.x10.mx/:1
```

on the google chrome dev concole

and by the looks of it it started at line one which is

`<html>`

and i looked everywhere and couldent find a fix besides checking if the file exists and it dose

But i did find something that said the .httaccess has something to do with it so im not sure its beacuse i added a offline/maintenance function to it

.httaccess

```
# -FrontPage-
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
### Maintenance Mode ###    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(offline\.php|images/offline\.png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ offline\.php [L]
### end of Maintenance Mode ###
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName killerducky1.x10.mx
AuthUserFile /home/killerdu/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/killerdu/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

offline.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>We are offline !</title>  
  </head>
  <body>
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url('images/offline.png');
    background-color: #eee;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: 1387px 729px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like your htaccess redirects the `offline.png` to `offline.php` which is an text/html file

Comment: So pretty much what your saying is that my browse is reading `offline.png` as a text file ?

Comment: Maybe `AddType image/png .png` is missing?

Comment: Nope still Getting the error

Comment: Thanks for the help prix ! but still didn't fix it

Comment: @KillerDucky1 well if that is not working then you might have another `.htaccess` file on the images folder that is removing that rule, did you re-upload the `.htaccess` into the public_html folder?

Comment: @Prix I have a cpanel so i didn't reupload it i just edit it and also i dont have a nother `.htaccess` file in my images file

Comment: @Prix sorry about that it did fix it it just turns out i was in mobile view on the developer console thanks !

Comment: glad it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offline\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ offline\.php [L]
```

The above tells that anything not start with `/offline.php` will be redirected to `offline.php` which includes image.

You can fix it by changing it into:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(offline\.php|images/offline\.png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ offline\.php [L]
```