# HTML5 FILE SYSTEM: file not created on device

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-filesystem

I have used html5 file system for createing a file on local disk. It's working fine on computer (desk or laptop), file is been created, data stored and also retrived from the the file.
But When runing on mobile device (android) it not working as aspected.
If any body have idea whats going wrong on device, plz share.
I have read about HTML5 from this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

I tried for log details, i found this:
`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://10.4.71.200/stage/not_found.html".`

Answer (score 1):

That may be because HTML5 FileSystem API only works on Chrome 40+ on Android

http://caniuse.com/#search=FileSystem

Edit:
You may have noticed the **Heads up!** notice at the beginning of the post you read

Comment: But i have used it with firefox and its working smoothly. And i am using android chrome v40.0.2214, so it should work with it.

Comment: hm... Some code or log would help (me or other people) to help you

Comment: I have added the log error, plz check wheather it's useful.

Comment: Looks like an image URI in a CSS file problem to me.
Check out these similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057030/resource-interpreted-as-image-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-magento
, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724409/resource-interpreted-as-image-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-error